# Create server report to html format

Tags: powershell, formatting, html

I have created the following bit of spaghetti that creates a report for me. It pulls into excel just fine but ideally I would like the output in html. Can I just pipe my output to convert it? How would I include column heading?

```
[array]$Serverlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=blah, DC=blah, DC=blah" | where {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Test*")}
$num = 1

foreach ($servername in $Serverlist) {

   $version = try {invoke-command -computername $Servername.name {WMIC OS Get Name} -ErrorAction Stop | Select-string -Pattern 'Windows Server'} catch { $ServerVersion = "Denied, Check WinRM" }

   if ($Serverversion -notlike "Denied*") {
   
      $ServerVersion = $version.line.Substring(0,($version.line.IndexOf('|C:\')))
      $cpu = invoke-command -computername $servername.name {Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceID', 'NumberOfCores'}
      $ram = invoke-command -computername $servername.name {(Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum}; $ram = [math]::Round($ram/1gb) 
      $disk = invoke-command -computername $servername.name {(Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Measure-Object -Sum size).sum}; $disk = [math]::Round($disk/1gb)
      $sockets = $cpu.DeviceID.count
      
      } else {
       
      $cpu = ""; $ram = ""; $disk =""

      }
   
   $server = $servername.name + "|" + $serverversion + "|" + $sockets + "|" + $cpu.numberofcores+ "|" + $ram + "|" + $disk 
   write-host "Examining server" $num "of" $Serverlist.Count 
   Add-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\report.txt -value $server
   
   $Serverversion = ""; $sqlversion = ""; $num++
            
}
```

Comment: Did you try what happens if you simply pipe it to `ConvertTo-HTML`? Did you read `Get-Help ConvertTo-Html -Online` ? If so where exactly is the problem or what do you want differently

Comment: I ended up embedding the mark up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this SO Q&A discussion, which is similar to what you are asking for here:

> [sending bulk mail with HTML formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65950659/sending-bulk-mail-with-html-formatted/65951163#65951163)

Though it's specifically about email, the approach would be the same for your use case and the resource pointers would directly cover your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a readable report now. Alternated the colour of the rows to make it a bit easier to read.

```
[array]$Serverlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=blah, DC=blah, DC=blah" | where {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Test*")}

Remove-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot\report.html
$header = '<TABLE width=100% border=1 style="background-color:CCCCCC"><TR><TD width=10%><B>Server Name</B></TD><TD width=50%><B>OS Version</B></TD><TD width=10%><B>Sockets</B></TD><TD width=10%><B>Cores</B></TD><TD width=10%><B>Ram</B></TD><TD width=10%><B>Total Disk</B></TD></TR></TABLE>'
Add-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\report.html -value $header
$num = 1

foreach ($servername in $Serverlist) {

   $version = try {invoke-command -computername $Servername.name {WMIC OS Get Name} -ErrorAction Stop | Select-string -Pattern 'Windows Server'} catch { $ServerVersion = "Denied, Check WinRM" }

   if ($Serverversion -notlike "Denied*") {
   
      $ServerVersion = $version.line.Substring(0,($version.line.IndexOf('|C:\')))
      $cpu = invoke-command -computername $servername.name {Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_Processor' | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceID', 'Name', 'NumberOfCores'}
      $ram = invoke-command -computername $servername.name {(Get-WmiObject -class "cim_physicalmemory" | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum}; $ram = [math]::Round($ram/1gb) 
      $disk = invoke-command -computername $servername.name {(Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Measure-Object -Sum size).sum}; $disk = [math]::Round($disk/1gb)
      $sockets = $cpu.DeviceID.count
      
      } else {
       
      $cpu = ""; $ram = ""; $disk =""

      }  

   if ($num % 2) {$colour = 'style=background-color:ffffff'} else {$colour = 'style=background-color:ffffcc'}
   $server = '<TABLE width=100% border=1 ' + $colour + '><TR><TD width=10%>' + $servername.name + '</TD><TD width=50%>' + $serverversion + '</TD><TD width=10%>' + $sockets + '</TD><TD width=10%>' + $cpu.numberofcores+ '</TD><TD width=10%>' + $ram + '</TD><TD width=10%>' + $disk + '</TD></TR>'
   write-host "Examining server" $num "of" $Serverlist.Count 
   Add-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\report.html -value $server 
      
   $Serverversion = ""; $sqlversion = ""; $num++
            
}
```